# Fundamental representation of $O(3)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to check if the fundamental representation of $O(3)$ is irreducible on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{C}^3$. I want to use isomorphism properties.

I know this relation exists
$$
\mathfrak{o}(3)\sim \mathfrak{so}(3) \sim \mathfrak{su}(2)
$$

and I know that the irreps of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ comes from irreps of $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

So, I would say that $\mathfrak{o}(3)$ has 3-dimentional irrep on $\mathbb{R}^3$, the same of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, but I'm not sure.

How are the representation related by algebra isomorphism?

Let be $D$ an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$.

How can I construct the equivalent representation $D'$ of $\mathfrak{o}(3)$ starting from $D$? Is D' a representation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{C}^3$?

Comment: Do you mean the sim to mean equivalent types of representations? And do you mean your lower-case letters to mean the associated Lie algebras?

Comment: Yes, with lower-case letters I mean the associated Lie Algebra

Comment: I want to relate the irreducible representation of $\mathbb{su}(2)$ with that irreps of $\mathbb{o}(3)$